# How to link and execute a PHP file from a Javascript script?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to call and execute a segment of PHP code located on an external file. I understand the way of doing that involves jQuery. Here's is my code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
         $.post("ext.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
        .done(function(data) {
          alert("Data Loaded: " + data); });

        $(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).load('ext.php');});

    </script>  

</body>
```

And here is the external file (ext.php):

```
<?php
echo $_POST['name'] . ' and- ' . $_POST['time'];
?>
```

The code should print the variables `name` and `time` on the screen (as well as in the popup window). The popup works fine, but the code doesn't print the veriables on the screen.

Thanks :)

Comment: ext.php is unequal ofek.php. In the callback you pass to $.post, insert something into the DOM. Why would you expect this to put the "variables on the screen"?

Comment: Try $("body").load("ext.php");  Or better yet a specific element in the DOM.

Answer (score 4):

Forgive me if you know this already, but in case you don't:

You are using `$.post()` in your example, which is a streamlined form of the `$.ajax()` jQuery method. I suggest using this easier (but larger) format until you are very confident with AJAX. `$.ajax()` also allows you to do much more than the streamlined (quick) `$.post` method.

I added a couple of input boxes for you to type some information. Also, you need a place to put the stuff to appear on the screen, so I created a DIV for that.

Ajax posts data to an external php file, which processes the data it receives, and sends back an answer.  It looks like this:

FILE #1:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#mybutt').click(function() {
                    var nom = $('#yername').val();
                    var tim = $('#thetime').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "receiving_file.php",
                        data: 'name=' + nom + '&time=' +tim,
                        success:function(data){
                            alert('This was sent back: ' + data);
                            $('#report').html(data);
                        }
                    }); //END ajax

                }); //END click fn

            }); //END document.ready
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

Name: <input type="text" id="yername"><br>
Time: <input type="text" id="thetime"><br><br>
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Go">
<br><Br>
<div id="report"></div>
```

FILE #2: receiving_file.php

```
<?php
    echo 'You entered: ' . $_POST['name'] . ' and- ' . $_POST['time'];
```

Comment: I already flagged this as low quality because of its first version. :|now much better +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use post with load that way i think:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).load('ext.php', {
        name: "john",
        time: "2pm"
    }, function (data) {
        $('body').append(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        $.post("ext.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }).done(function(data) { 
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            $('body').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```